Alternative to TYPE_PHONE for API Level 26 and Above to Ensure Toast or Hardware Views Appear Above OverlayView
I am showing overlayview of type TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY which works after 25 API Level but toast comes behind of overlayview but I found  TYPE_PHONE works well but It is deprecated in API Level 26. So I need alternatove of type_phone in apilevel 26 sothat toast/anyother hardware view will come above overlayview
Dialog(this).apply {
            // Common properties defined once
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE)
            } else {
                window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY)
            }
            window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.appbgdark)
            window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
            window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) // Set once
            setCancelable(false)  // Set once (if it's constant)
        }
    }

